# Using DataGrid content in other View in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am making a WPF application with the design pattern MVVM, in my next step i need to use the content of a DataGrid,shown in MainWindow, in another Window.
Is there a way to use items created in a specific Window in other Windows passing by ViewModels ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the MainViewModel as a reference to your other view models.  That way you can access the data from the MainViewModel from your other view models.

```
 public class MainViewModel
{
    public AnotherViewModel avm { get; set; }
    public int ImportantInfo { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        avm = new AnotherViewModel(this);
    }
}

public class AnotherViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel mvm { get; set; }
    public AnotherViewModel(MainViewModel mvm)
    {
        this.mvm = mvm;
        MoreImportantINfo = this.mvm.ImportantInfo;
    }
    public int MoreImportantINfo { get; set; }      
}
```

This type of reference is just an example that could be used in a smaller project.  For larger projects this same idea is implemented through dependency injection (DI).  Check out this post tor read more on DI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

Another approach is to use events.  Have the any `Viewmodel` that wants data from the `MainViewModel` subscribe to an event that the `MainViewModel` invokes with the desired data.

Comment: Isn't a better to design to either use dependency injection, or messaging via an event aggregator or better yet have shared content in a service.

Comment: yes it is better to use DI unless it is a smaller project.  I was just giving a basic example of how to share resources.